# It seems that my react file is totally ignored when I browse it in my web browser, how can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, visual-studio-code, flask

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function NumberInputForm() {
  console.log('MyComponent rendering...');
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setNumber(value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Validate the input as a positive number
    const parsedNumber = parseFloat(number);
    if (parsedNumber > 0) {
      // Handle the positive number (e.g., send it to the server, perform calculations, etc.)
      console.log('Positive number:', parsedNumber);
    } else {
      // Handle invalid input (e.g., show an error message)
      console.log('Invalid input:', number);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Enter a positive number:
        <input
          type="number"
          value={number}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          min="0" // Set the minimum value as 0 to enforce positive numbers
          step="any" // Allow any decimal input
          required // Make the input field required
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default NumberInputForm;


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .centered-text {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      color: rgb(0, 128, 255);
    }
  </style>
  <style>
    .multiline-text {
      white-space: pre-line;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Data Collection</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <!-- Include React library -->
  <script src="../node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>

  <!-- Include React DOM library -->
  <script src="../node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

  <script src="../src/components/component1.js"></script>

  <div class="centered-text">
    <div class="multiline-text">
      <h2>What is the name of the stock</h2>
      <input type="text" id="stockname" name="stockname" placeholder="Enter text here">
      <h2>1. How much is it undervalued?</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you don't bundle your component...

You need to transform JSX first before import it into the browser.

Comment: Isn't single file distribution OK?

Comment: Browser can't understand JSX, this isn't about single file or not you could use some like [htm](https://github.com/developit/htm#installation) if you wanna just fast prototyping, but I prefer to use a bundler